# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]:

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I keep getting this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE profile_id = '20' AND user_id = '2'' at line 4 in C:\MAMP\htdocs\JavaScript module\Week 3\edit.php:71 Stack trace: #0 C:\MAMP\htdocs\JavaScript module\Week 3\edit.php(71): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\MAMP\htdocs\JavaScript module\Week 3\edit.php on line 71

I've tried looking online, and I don't think any of these are reserved words, so I can't see where I'm going wrong. This code worked previously for a different database. How can I fix this problem?

Code (line 71 is the penultimate one ( **':su' => $_POST['summary'])** )):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE Profile SET
         first_name = :fn, last_name = :ln,
         email = :em, headline = :he, summary = :su,
         WHERE profile_id = :pid AND user_id = :uid');

$stmt->execute(array(
     ':pid' => $_REQUEST['profile_id'],
     ':uid' => $_SESSION['user_id'],
     ':fn'  => $_POST['first_name'],
     ':ln'  => $_POST['last_name'],
     ':em'  => $_POST['email'],
     ':he'  => $_POST['headline'],
     ':su'  => $_POST['summary'])
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra comma before `WHERE`

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE Profile SET 
     first_name = :fn, last_name = :ln,
     email = :em, headline = :he, summary = :su 
     WHERE profile_id = :pid AND user_id = :uid');
```

Comment: Thanks very much, thought it was something simple, but could not see for looking.